# Cloudformation beanstalk change from "OK" to "no data" state when i remove all traffic ACL entry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i have  a elastic beanstalk that is running with sample node beanstalk application. it is running inside a public subnet with ACL entry as below
ACL  - inbound all traffic 0.0.0.0/0 allow  - outbound all traffic 0.0.0.0/0 allow

and SG is open as well on inbound - port 80 (0.0.0.0/0) and outbound - 0.0.0.0/0(all traffic).

but when i remove the ACL entry (all traffic) and add a 80 (0.0.0.0/0) entry in ACL inbound then after some time beanstalk move to **No data** state.

can somebody help me to understand what i am missing.

Comment: Do you really have to modify default NACLs. Does it work if you use default NACLs?

Comment: i have attached the public subnet to custom ACL which have the above rule (all traffic one).but i want to secure my environment to be open for particular port.
and yes beanstalk was working with above ACL entries.
getting below error in enhanced monitoring - **No data received from the instance**.

Comment: Can you please show your new NACL? You only wrote "add a 80 (0.0.0.0/0) entry" but where? inboud, outbound? What are exact rules and their priorties.

Comment: @marcin i have added the rule in inbound
Added below rules but still showing in no data state.

=>  200 HTTP (80) TCP (6) 80 0.0.0.0/0  Allow
=>  300 HTTPS (443) TCP (6) 443 0.0.0.0/0  Allow
=>  400 All ICMP - IPv4 ICMP (1) All 0.0.0.0/0  Allow
=>  550 Custom UDP UDP (17) 123 0.0.0.0/0  Allow